# Shell script to find files after certain modified date and sort them in order of modified date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to find all files after certain modified date from a directory in the sorting order of modified date using shell script. This is one of the part of my current shell script.

Condition contains two steps: 1) Fetch files from a directory after certain modified date.
2) sort the files by modified date.

Current directory contains files like this:

```
Mar 28 11:14 file_H_1
Apr  2 16:37 file_K_2
Apr  1 21:43 file_H_3
Apr 16 19:16 file_H_4
Apr 16 21:00 file_H_5
Apr 16 12:00 file_L_6
Apr  9 14:08 file_B_7
Apr  4 00:39 file_H_8
Apr  4 00:39 file_H_9
Apr  4 00:39 file_C_10
Apr  4 00:39 file_H_11
Mar 27 14:39 file_H_12
```

I want final output as a list of files with modified date after "2018-04-09 00:00:00" and in order by modified date.
OUTPUT should be:

```
file_B_7
file_L_6
file_H_4
file_H_5
```

I tried this:
1) For getting files after certain modified date

```
find . -type f -newermt "2018-04-09 00:00:00"
OUTPUT of this:
file_L_6
file_H_5
file_B_7
file_H_4
```

2) order the files on modified date

```
ls -lt
OUTPUT of this
Apr 16 21:00 file_H_5
Apr 16 19:16 file_H_4
Apr 16 12:00 file_L_6
Apr  9 14:08 file_B_7
Apr  4 00:39 file_H_8
Apr  4 00:39 file_H_9
Apr  4 00:39 file_C_10
Apr  4 00:39 file_H_11
Apr  2 16:37 file_K_2
Apr  1 21:43 file_H_3
Mar 28 11:14 file_H_1
Mar 27 14:39 file_H_12
```

But I am struggling to combine these two conditions.

I tried this also but it is sorting on file name not on modified date:

```
find . -type f -newermt "2018-04-9 00:00:00" | sort -n | while read file_name; do
echo file=$file_name
done
    OUTPUT of this:
    file_B_7
    file_H_4
    file_H_5
    file_L_6
```

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `xargs ls` you can also insert the find output directly into the `ls` command line:

```
ls -tr `find -type f -newermt "2018-04-09 00:00:00"`
```

Note that both approaches would fail if not all the filenames fit into one command line - `xargs ls` silently by not sorting correctly, this here with an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `find` and `ls -t` with a pipe:

```
find -type f -newermt "2018-04-09 00:00:00" | xargs ls -tl
```

`xargs` gives the output of `find` to `ls`.

In case some of your filenames have spaces, use this:

```
find -type f -newermt "2018-04-09 00:00:00" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tl
```

`-print0` option allows to use the filename deleimiter as `\0`. `xargs` expects this delimiter with the option `-0`.

Note that you can use `ls -ltr` if you want the reverse time order.

In any case, you shouldn't parse the result of `ls` ([Ref](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: Add `awk '{print "\""$0"\""}'` in between to handle filenames with spaces.

Comment: @Kokogino I would not do that, Instead use `print0`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
ls -t | egrep "$(find * -maxdepth 0 -type f -newermt "2018-04-9 00:00:00" -print | sed 's/|/\\|/g' | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`ls -t | find . -type f -newermt "2018-04-09 00:00:00"`